# Turning application's features on/off

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config, config

I have several features in my .net application that I would like to be able to turn on/off. As I understand there several options available:

- Config file
- Registry
- Custom xml file

I would like to avoid anything related to Windows registry due to the security reasons. At the same time what I don't like about config file/custom xml files is that it can be access by the client (for example the client can turn on the feature he/she didn't pay for).

I would really appreciate an advice on my problem. Is there a way to track changes made in config file (I still want to be able to change other settings), or can I for example build some process that is gonna run before the release of my application and gonna ask what features to turn on/off and save this settings somewhere (not available for a client).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what about a database?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Thanks a lot for the reply. The thing is that I have a Generic application that includes a lot of different functionality and most of the clients won't need all of it. Therefore I would rather apply some setting to the app once (preferably at the release stage) then reading something from a database every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see following options:

1. Every time you application is started connect to remote server or remote database to check user permissions. Main weakness: user must have internet connection when using your application.
2. Store it locally (it does not matter which way), but in encrypted form. The easiest option is to use certificate. Main weakness: you have to provide "infrastructure" to manage licence keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Garath. I will try the encryption.

Answer (score 2):

There's many ways to handle this situation, but one of the easiest may be to encrypt the configuration file.

- Use an asymmetric encryption system (like RSA)
- During the build process, encrypt the file with the private key, and distribute it along with the application
- In the application's code, decrypt the file using the public key, and activate the features accordingly

You can also use a symmetric encryption system, but the advantage of the asymmetric approach is that the end-user cannot generate a fake file even if he retrieves the key by reverse-engineering the application (he can still tamper directly with the application's binaries though).

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to have a place where your data is safe from tampering you can sign the app.config. That way it cannot be changed, but it is still readable xml. It's not encrypted.

More info on signing XML [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx).